# How to sort object array in ascending order based on instance variables

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort an object array in Java. I have created for example:

```
Employee[] hourly = new Employee[];
```

Then had the user input values for the `name`, `id`, `hourly pay`. Such as ask

```
System.out.println("Please enter employee name, id and hourly pay");
```

Then storing the `name` as a sting `id` as `int` and `hourly pay` as double. From there I needed to sort the object array `Employee` by hourly pay in ascending order.

I want to do this without comparator or array list.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use either of the tools designed for comparing?

Comment: So have you tried to implement *any* sorting algorithm yourself yet?

Comment: "I want to do this without comparator or array list." That's kind or like going fishing without hooks, net, or spear. Why not use the tools that the language provides? But if you really don't want to use the built-in tools, then write your own sort: bubblesort, insertion sort, quicksort, etc.

Comment: OP is a [noodler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noodling).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to do this without comparator or array list.

You can either let your Employee class implements `Comparable` then sort it with `Arrays.sort(employeeArray);`

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>
{
    //Constructors and other members not shown
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee e){
        return (getHourlyPay() - e.getHourlyPay());
    }
}
Arrays.sort(employeeArray);
```

**OR**

Implement your own sorting method where you sort according to the hourly pay of each employee object. The way how you sort it will be similar to sorting an integer array.

For example, instead of writing..

```
if (array[i] < min)  //where array[i] is of type int
```

you will be writing..

```
if(employee[i].getHourlyPay() < min)
```